# Booting ubuntu directly

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, grub-efi

I have installed Ubuntu alongside windows but the problem is I am unable to get the dual boot screen where we have the windows boot loader listed, instead of that the computer directly boots into Ubuntu.....I  am unable to see the grub screen.

Any suggestions how to enable the dual boot list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling grub? check this link out
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial link.....It solved my problem....